# I want to ask something about best shaving solution, Can i ask here?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I want to ask something about best shaving solution for men, Can i ask here?

It's not related to fitness and Nutrition. if fitness.stackexchange.com is not a right place for this then is there any other stackexchange site?

Comment: You might hit [Art of Manliness](http://www.artofmanliness.com). Brett has some great information there about all things manly, including shaving.

Comment: You can check out the [Cosmetology Stack Exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41769/cosmetology?referrer=39RAzV_9Bgs1) on Area 51.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think this would be on-topic for [any site in the network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) at this time.

Also, questions that contain the word "best" are generally a bad fit for our engine, as they turn into an infinite list of opinions..

Comment: I mean preferred.

Comment: Either way @Jitendra, shaving has nothing to do with exercise or nutrition, so it would be off-topic.

Comment: @Ivo - That I know and have already mentioned in question

Comment: "Preferred" wouldn't change the meaning of your question anyway.